# Calculate the count as per time difference using aggregate function in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I need to calculate the no of records as per some time interval using MongoDB aggregate function. I am showing my collection below.

allocation:

```
state1                 state2                              createdDate

test1                  test2                     2019-08-16T09:41:22.202Z

test1                  test2                     2019-08-16T09:41:22.202Z

test3                  test4                     2019-08-16T09:41:22.202Z

test1                  test2                     2019-08-16T09:41:22.202Z
```

In my allocation collection I have `state1,state2,createdDate` column and here I need to calculate the no of record within some time interval as per user input (`i.e-test1 & test2`). Here Using aggregate function I need to the result like below.

```
difference                  count

0-6HRs                        2
6-12HRS                       0

................................
................................
```

The time difference will calculate from `createdDate` column value.

Comment: Don't be shy exposing your research efforts.

Comment: I searched a lot but there is no direct aggregate query I think.

Comment: Fair enough, there are no aggregation function to calculate number of records with some time interval as per user input. You will need to use a combination of existing operators. The thing is there is a downwote arrow with title "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" which very precisely describes your question in its current edition

Comment: @satya Is this time difference between consecutive ```createdDate```? Can you please post some sample data set and expected output from them?

Comment: @satya Could you please explain more? Is it related to `createdDate` or `state1 & state2`?

Comment: I am minded to agree with @Alex, this appears to be either unresearched, or at the very least any research that was done is not shown.